# iOS ipa unattended install without popup? (via ota mdm push)

Tags: ios, mdm

I have a working custom-made mdm server, with enrolled iPads that respond correctly to pushed commands.

I currently deploy .ipa application on theses devices using the `InstallApplication` command, however, each time, the device displays a popup to ask for confirmation before installing/updating the app.

I'm currently asking for the highest available `AccessRight` (8191) in the `com.apple.mdm` payload.

I've heard that it was somehow possible to perform true unattended installs without this popup? Is it true? Does it require the configurator (can't be an option in my case, 100% ota)?

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of unattended (silent) app install through MDM on iOS.

Based on MDM documentation it will always request a user approval for InstallApplication command.

Regarding Apple Configurator. You can make a device supervised and install MDM configuration profile on it. This way, initial configuration should be done through a tether, but you can do any follow up configurations through MDM. I doubt it, but may be supervised devices behaves differently (don't require a user acceptance) for InstallApplication command.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available for MDMs with iOS 7.

Chances are it will take your MDM software a while to implement the feature and make available to you though. At the time of this writing mine is "working on it for a future release."